# Compiling SASS using jRuby

Tags: css, ruby, ant, sass, jruby

I'm using jruby to compile scss files to css using ant build script.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="test" default="compileSCSS" basedir=".">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <path id="JRuby">
        <fileset file="libs/jruby-complete-1.7.18.jar"/> <!-- Location of JRuby jar file -->
    </path> 
    <target name="compileSCSS">
        <echo message="Compiling scss files..." />
        <property name="filesIn" value="style.scss" />
        <property name="fileOutDir" value="output/" />
        <property name="root" value="." />
        <script language="ruby" classpathref="JRuby">
            <![CDATA[
                require './libs/sass/lib/sass'
                require './libs/sass/lib/sass/exec'
                files = Dir.glob($project.getProperty('filesIn'))
                files.each do |file|
                   opts = Sass::Exec::Sass.new(["--load-path", File.dirname(file), file, File.join($project.getProperty('fileOutDir'), File.basename(file, ".*") + ".css")])
                   opts.parse
                end
            ]]>
        </script>
        <echo message="Done compiling SCSS source files." />
    </target>
</project>
```

This is my build script. I'm using jruby 1.7.8 and SASS source code from github (version 3.4.9).

Its throwing **exception** :

```
javax.script.ScriptException: org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: 
(NameError) uninitialized constant Sass::Exec::Sass
```

Please help. What could be the Issue?

Comment: This is strange `require` sentences in your code. Why not just `require 'sass'` and `require 'sass/exec'`?

Comment: This is because i have sass source code as a standalone one in my libs directory.

Comment: Try to change `require` to `require_relative`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I changed 
`opts = Sass::Exec::Sass.new(["--load-path", File.dirname(file), file, File.join($project.getProperty('fileOutDir'), File.basename(file, ".*") + ".css")])`

To
`opts = Sass::Exec::SassScss.new(["--load-path", File.dirname(file), file, File.join($project.getProperty('fileOutDir'), File.basename(file, ".*") + ".css")], 'scss')`

Worked for me.